# libserialport does not write data to port

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a serial device that uses a Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART chip; I've installed the driver and can succesfully communicate with several devices using manufacturer provided graphical user interfaces.

However, I'm currently trying to use [libserialport](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport) to communicate with a particular device that I have the serial specification for. My code is below:

```
 // find list of available devices
 sp_return status = sp_list_ports(&ports);

 // list available ports
 int j = 0;
 for (j = 0; ports[j]; j++) {
  printf("Found port %d: %s\n", j, sp_get_port_name(ports[j]));
 }

 // connect to serial port
 struct sp_port *port = ports[1]; // /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
 sp_set_baudrate(port, 9600);
 sp_set_bits(port, 8);
 sp_set_stopbits(port, 1);
 sp_set_parity(port, SP_PARITY_NONE);
 status = sp_open(port, SP_MODE_READ_WRITE);

 // attempt first write
 uint8_t buf[] = {0x02, 0x43, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03};
 status = sp_blocking_write(port, buf, 10, 0);
 printf("Bytes written: %d\n", status);
```

The code includes extensive error checking to verify that each function returns correctly however I have removed it for clarity. The code above successfully prints that it wrote 10 bytes to the serial port.

However, the device does not respond - to remove the device from the equation, I connected the serial signal through an oscilloscope and pulse detector and confirmed that no bytes are being written to the serial line (despite libserialport stating that it wrote 10 bytes).

Has anyone run into this problem before? This is running on OS X 10.11

I have tried reinstalling the device driver and manually writing bytes with `echo` and `cat` but the end-result is no bytes being written onto the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got to work. I was using minicom to read what was sent but I couldn't get it to work at anything faster than 9600 baud.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libserialport.h"

typedef unsigned int uint8_t;


int main(void)
{

struct sp_port *ports;
struct sp_port **psp_ports;
int i;
int j;
uint8_t mychar;

ports = (struct sp_port*)malloc(sizeof(ports)*2);
psp_ports = &ports;
int status = sp_list_ports(&psp_ports);
printf("sp_list_ports returned %d\n",status);
// list available ports
printf("port: %s\n",sp_get_port_name(psp_ports[0]));
printf("port: %s\n",sp_get_port_name(psp_ports[1]));
j = 0;
sp_set_baudrate(psp_ports[j], 9600);
sp_set_bits(psp_ports[j], 8);
sp_set_stopbits(psp_ports[j], 1);
sp_set_parity(psp_ports[j], SP_PARITY_NONE);
status = sp_open(psp_ports[j], SP_MODE_READ_WRITE);
printf("status = %d\n",status);
if(status < 0)
    return 0;

for(i = 0;i < 100;i++)
{
    for(mychar = 0x21;mychar < 0x7e;mychar++)
        status = sp_nonblocking_write(psp_ports[j], &mychar, 1);
}       
sp_free_port(psp_ports[j]);
sp_close(psp_ports[j]);
return 0;
}
```

I searched all over, and on github and I couldn't find any examples of how to use libserialport. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

from the header file: libserialport.h:

```
enum sp_return sp_list_ports(struct sp_port ***list_ptr);

/**
 * Make a new copy of an sp_port structure.
 *
 * The user should allocate a variable of type "struct sp_port *" and pass a
 * pointer to this to receive the result.
 *
 * The copy should be freed after use by calling sp_free_port().
 *
 * @param[in] port Pointer to a port structure. Must not be NULL.
 * @param[out] copy_ptr If any error is returned, the variable pointed to by
 *                      copy_ptr will be set to NULL. Otherwise, it will be set
 *                      to point to the newly allocated copy. Must not be NULL.
 *
 * @return SP_OK upon success, a negative error code otherwise.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 */
```

don't you have to use malloc on 'ports' and then use `sp_free_port()` ?